# Python dictionary manipulation into list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I m fairly new to python and having a hard time solving this problem,
I have a dictionary in format:

```
{'tag1_batch1_st': OrderedDict([(0.0, '59.83163071'), (1.0, '18.94903946'), (2.0, '48.38692856'), (3.0, '0.05321884'), (4.0, '4.20608902'), (5.0, '01.66112137'), (6.0, '0.59775162'), (7.0, '37.17335892'), (8.0, '0.78234863'), (9.0, '1.67506027')]), 'tag_batch_st ': OrderedDict([(0.0, '58.83163071'), (1.0, '48.94903946'), (2.0, '38.38692856'), (3.0, '45.05321884'), (4.0, '40.20608902'), (5.0, '38.66112137'), (6.0, '37.59775162'), (7.0, '37.17335892'), (8.0, '36.78234863'), (9.0, '36.67506027')])}
```

I want to convert it into a list like this:

```
[{'tag1_batch1_st': '59.83163071', 'num': 0.0, 'tag_batch_st': '58.83163071'}, ...... ]
```

I know, I can use for loop and iterate over the dictionary and create the list, but any approach which would require less iterations and methods like groupby() would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: explain the logic of constructing the expected result

Comment: Your example data could be laid out better to make what you want easier to see

Comment: The result is created by a database dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no approach that'll give a complexity less than O(n) -  *n* is the number of key, value pairs in the OrderedDict. You have iterate on every pair, so no such thing as less iterations.

You can iterate on the dict values' key-value pairs (i.e. key-value pairs of OrderDict) simultaneously by zipping them and then build new dicts using the new pair and adding a new key entry:

```
lst = []
for (num, st1), (_, st2) in zip(*map(dict.items, dct.values())):
   d = dict(zip(dct.keys(), (st1, st2)))
   d['num'] = num
   lst.append(d)
```

---

```
[{'tag1_batch1_st': '59.83163071', 'tag_batch_st ': '58.83163071', 'num': 0.0}, 
 {'tag1_batch1_st': '18.94903946', 'tag_batch_st ': '48.94903946', 'num': 1.0}, 
 ...
]
```

---

In case you have more keys in the dictionary, you can use `map(zip, ...)` to collect all the values from the ordered dicts in a tuple, and the zip the tuple with the parent dictionary keys:

```
for (num, _), sts in map(zip, *map(dict.items, dct.values())):
   d = dict(zip(dct.keys(), sts))
   d['num'] = num
   lst.append(d)
```

Comment: Does not give the desired output, both the keys 'k' and 'tag_batch_st', have the same value. But, if you look at the output, the output is different.

Comment: @ShivinAgarwal Didn't notice. So why keep us guessing about how the value for `'tag_batch_st'` was created?

Comment: its a database dump.

Comment: It throws error:  ' TypeError: items() takes no arguments (1 given) '

Comment: @ShivinAgarwal You've assigned the builtin `dict` using `dict = ..` somewhere. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Now its working, after your edit. But can you please explain what you did? or provide a link for the same. Thank you.

Comment: but, what if it contained more keys like 'tag2_batch2_st' and so on, which would be dynamic in nature, then?

Comment: @ShivinAgarwal I've updated the answer with code handling such cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159901/discussion-between-shivin-agarwal-and-moses-koledoye).

Answer (score 0):

You can use default dict and lambda :

> Two line solution :

```
from collections import OrderedDict,defaultdict
a={'tag1_batch1_st': OrderedDict([(0.0, '59.83163071'), (1.0, '18.94903946'), (2.0, '48.38692856'), (3.0, '0.05321884'), (4.0, '4.20608902'), (5.0, '01.66112137'), (6.0, '0.59775162'), (7.0, '37.17335892'), (8.0, '0.78234863'), (9.0, '1.67506027')]), 'tag_batch_st ': OrderedDict([(0.0, '58.83163071'), (1.0, '48.94903946'), (2.0, '38.38692856'), (3.0, '45.05321884'), (4.0, '40.20608902'), (5.0, '38.66112137'), (6.0, '37.59775162'), (7.0, '37.17335892'), (8.0, '36.78234863'), (9.0, '36.67506027')])}

default_dict = defaultdict(list)
list(map(lambda x:[default_dict[key].append(value) for key,value in x.items()],a.values()))


print([{'tag1_batch1_st':value[0],'tag_batch1_st':value[1],'num':key} for key,value in default_dict.items()])
```

> output:

```
[{'num': 0.0, 'tag_batch1_st': '59.83163071', 'tag1_batch1_st': '58.83163071'}, {'num': 1.0, 'tag_batch1_st': '18.94903946', 'tag1_batch1_st': '48.94903946'}, {'num': 2.0, 'tag_batch1_st': '48.38692856', 'tag1_batch1_st': '38.38692856'}, {'num': 3.0, 'tag_batch1_st': '0.05321884', 'tag1_batch1_st': '45.05321884'}, {'num': 4.0, 'tag_batch1_st': '4.20608902', 'tag1_batch1_st': '40.20608902'}, {'num': 5.0, 'tag_batch1_st': '01.66112137', 'tag1_batch1_st': '38.66112137'}, {'num': 6.0, 'tag_batch1_st': '0.59775162', 'tag1_batch1_st': '37.59775162'}, {'num': 7.0, 'tag_batch1_st': '37.17335892', 'tag1_batch1_st': '37.17335892'}, {'num': 8.0, 'tag_batch1_st': '0.78234863', 'tag1_batch1_st': '36.78234863'}, {'num': 9.0, 'tag_batch1_st': '1.67506027', 'tag1_batch1_st': '36.67506027'}]
```